# Как узнать идентификатор оф. приложения ВК и скачивать видео?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, oauth

Как узнать идентификатор приложения ВКонтакте?

Наткнулся на статью [habrahabr.ru/sandbox/57173/](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/57173/), где написано:

> Нехитрыми путями узнаем идентификатор приложения

Статья, к сожалению, уже не актуальна. Я так понимаю, этот самый идентификатор приложения не подходит, выдает:

```
{"error":"invalid_access","error_description":"Security issue"}
```

Может кто-нибудь научить, как это делать?

Answer (score 3):

ID официального приложения ВКонтакте под Android всё тот же: `2274003`.

Как его получить? Например, если вы пользуетесь ВКонтакте под Android, то это приложение есть у вас в [списке ваших приложений](https://vk.com/apps?act=settings), называется "Android". Откройте инструменты разработчика в вашем браузере, чтобы наблюдать выполняемые запросы, и нажмите «Настройки» напротив. POST-параметром `aid` передаётся как раз id приложения:

[image: POST запрос Настроек приложения ВКонтакте]

Другое дело, что во-первых, изменилась [схема запроса](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile) - надо указывать больше параметров. А во-вторых разработчики ВК тоже читают Хабр, и давно прикрыли эту «дыру», позволяющую получить такой простой доступ к видеозаписям. То, как можно получить `standalone` токен для обычных приложений, для этого доверенного приложения не срабатывает.

Так что с идентификатором приложения разобрались, но доступа к видео это не даёт.

**Что можно сделать**

[Зарегистрируйте](https://vk.com/apps?act=manage) собственное приложение ВК типа  `standalone`. Якобы оно будет работать с вашего мобильника/автономного устройства. Только таким доступны методы получения прямых ссылок на видео.

Далее, если оно будет работать на вашем сервере, нужно авторизоваться ВКонтакте с IP именно этого сервера, т.к. токен привязывается к адресу и с других адресов будет требовать капчу, или просто не сработает. Чтобы так авторизоваться, понадобится SSH доступ к серверу, чтобы сделать через него "тоннель". На вашем компьютере наберите что-то вроде:

```
ssh -f  login@11.22.33.44  -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8888  -N
```

где `11.22.33.44` - ip вашего сервера. Это «прокинет порт» 8888 с вашего компа через тот сервер. В браузере укажите порт прокси 8888. И теперь вы выходите в инет под ip адресом вашего сервера. Залогиньтесь во ВКонтакте и [авторизуйте](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile) ваше созданное приложение по ссылке вида:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=999999999&scope=video,offline&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&v=5.34&response_type=token
```

где вместо `999999999` поставьте id вашего созданного приложения. Просто составьте эту ссылку, включив необходимы разрешения, и откройте её в браузере (через тоннель). Откроется страница входа в ВК, потом запрос разрешения. Когда подтвердите, вас перенаправит на ссылку вида `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&token=xxx` – вот этот токен вам и нужен. Скопируйте, сохраните в вашем приложении.

Обратите внимание на параметр `expires` в ссылке с token'ом. Если не забыли среди разрешений указать `offline`, то будет `expires=0`, что означает бессрочный токен, который сможет прослужить вам хоть несколько лет. В противном случае токен сдохнет через час и придётся заново проделывать эту авторизацию.

Теперь ваше серверное приложение сможет скачивать видео клипы. Но давать кому попало пользоваться им – значит рано или поздно попасть в бан из-за подозрительно большого числа запросов к видео. Так что пользуйтесь умеренно сами с парой друзей, но не рассказывайте о приложении на Хабре : )

Answer (score 0):

Если вы уже создали приложение в http://vk.com/dev, то там можно посмотреть ID в вкладке Настройки. Для более детальной информации можете посмотреть [эту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/201074/) хорошую статью на хабре.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду